# Required plugin com.intellij.modules.androidstudio to be installed

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

I want to set up Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile on Intellij IDEA
I downloaded the Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile plugin and installed it but got a warning Require plugin 'com.intelliji.modules.androidstudio' to be installed
How can I resolved it
[image]

I install KMM plugin because I can't see any options for create KMM project on IDEA

[image]

Comment: KMM plugin is an Android Studio only plugin. You cannot use it from IDEA. I'm not 100% sure, but I think IDEA should have all the functionality you need bundled in, without having to use any plugin - at least I use it without issue. The only thing I don't do is run iOS apps from IDEA, not sure if that works.

Comment: Did you try to run KMM on IDEA?

Comment: Yes, I'm working on my KMM project from IDEA without problems

Comment: I updated my question. Could you help me?

Comment: You can use [online wizard](https://terrakok.github.io/kmp-web-wizard/)